# Bootstrap-vue issue with using v-b-modal directive and @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm a newbie to Vue and Bootstrap, I have a button like this:

```html
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
    v-b-modal.book-update-modal
    @click="editBook(book)">
Update</button>
```

`@click` binds to method `editBook()`

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      books: [],      
      editForm: {
        id: "",
        title: "",
        author: "",
        read: []
      },
      message: "",
      showMessage: false
    };
  },
methods: {
  function editBook(book){
      this.editForm = book;
  }
}
```

The issue is when I click this `button`, the modal won't show up unless I click it again. When I remove the `@click` binding from the `button` element, it works well.

I have no clue where's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

----Edit----

I remove the `v-b-modal.book-update-modal` and add `this.$refs.editBookModal.show();` to the `editBook(book)` method, it works well with single click on the button. But I'm still curious why the button need double-click to show the model when `v-b-modal.book-update-modal` is set.

Comment: Do you also have the code of your modal, or even better a https://codepen.io/pen/  where we could see the problems ourself

Comment: Thank you. https://codepen.io/lpwm/pen/KKKyLGE

Comment: Please make sure that your codepen is working, https://jsfiddle.net/dreijntjens/1sq45bn9/9/

Comment: Unfortunately I can not really explain why it is not working, but is seems that directive stops executing as your data is changed

Comment: Any change is state in your component (i.e. setting this.xxxx = something) will cause your component to re-render, and may cause the directive to be re-initialized due to the re-render.

Comment: You can also call `this.$bvModal.show('idOfModal')` in your click handler

Comment: Or try switching the order of the directive and the click handler when placing it on the button

Comment: @TroyMorehouse Yeap, I tried to call the show method in the click handler and it works well. Thanks for your mention, the re-render could be the reason.

Comment: @dreijntjens Thanks for your inspect, but the code uses `<b-*>` like grammar so it probably not working well in codepen, Troy's answer makes sense, perhaps the changes to the modal component causes a re-render.